# why my search code just show all data and dose not show the type result

Tags: php

hi i created a search box and code in php but when i press on search it just show all evenwhen input is null, and when i change  it to a $query variable it shows the messeage that i define for not the infprmation  that dose not exit even when i type the name correct

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{

$searchg=$_POST['search'];

$searchg=preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $searchg);

$query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE uploadfilename LIKE '%$searchg%'";
$res=$con2->query($query);

$cont=mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($cont==0){
    $output="not such as information finds";
}

 else{


   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    $filename = $row['uploadfilename'];
    $conte = $row['content'];

    $output.='<div>'.$filename.'</div>';
 }

}

}





   ?>
```

Comment: echo the query, check its right

Comment: not sure if this is correct but you can check, $res=$con2->query on one line, and then $cont=mysqli on the next, I think that should be $cont = $res->mysqli_num_rows($res); (comment as im not sure dont use mysqli i use pdo). It looks to me like you are mixing class methods with classic functions.

Comment: thanks i am new to phphow can use pdo could please show an example

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of your search using PDO instead of mysqli.(As you asked for a PDO example in the comment)
For your search example i will split answer into the following,
1.First of all set your connection to database.
2.Prepare the statement.
3.Bind parameters.
4.Execute.

For the above scenario this code will go to you "dbConnection.php" file,

```
try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //Your Query here
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

2.Require this file into your "search.php" file, which will be like,

```
require('dbConnection.php');
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
         $searchg=$_POST['search'];
         $searchg=preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $searchg);
         $sql="SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `uploadfilename` LIKE :keyword;";
         $q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
         $q->bindValue(':keyword','%'.$searchg.'%');
         $q->execute();
         while ($row=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
             // Here do what ever you want with the results i am showing array content with print_r. you can do what ever you want with resulting array.
             echo"<pre>".print_r($row,true)."</pre>";
         }
}//IF isset search
```